# Correct PATH location in .profile

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, .profile

I am running into some issues with installing `python` modules while using `python` versus `ipython` and I think it has to do with my `.profile` and `.bash_profile`.

My desired setup is to be able to leverage `homebrew`, `pip` and `easy_install` to install programs and modules, and have them install into the correct location so `python` and `ipython` point to the same source.  Here is the output of `which` for various programs:

```
mike$ which brew
/usr/local/bin/brew

mike$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

mike$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

mike$ which ipython
/usr/local/share/python/ipython
```

`.profile` output:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

`.bash_profile` output:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then source ~/.bashrc ; fi

export PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
```

What changes should I make so that when I install modules or programs, they automatically go into the correct location?

Comment: Your `PATH` has nothing to do with where modules get installed

Comment: Why is this a Ruby question?

Comment: related: [Install Scientific Python on Mac OS X](http://penandpants.com/2013/04/04/install-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `PATH` tells bash which executables to run when you type a certain command, not which modules to load in python. You can check where modules are installed by doing:

```
import module_name
print module_name.__file__
```

You're problem is likely due to either running different versions of python or having ipython use a different `PYTHONPATH`. Try doing:

```
import os
print os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]
```

in the two different interpreters. If it raises a KeyError, then try setting `PYTHONPATH` in your .bash_profile to the libraries you want, e.g.:

```
export PYTHONPATH=.:/usr/local/lib/python
```

If it's a version issue, then use the appropriate pip command (e.g. `pip-2.7` - see [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)). The same applies for easy_install.

For ruby I recommend using `rvm` and `gem install` (steps 6-8 of http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/). These tools are similar to python's pip and easy_install, allowing for seamless installation of ruby gems.

Comment: inside Python script look at `sys.path` which incorporates all including `PYTHONPATH` envvar.